# Spaces in Python arguments

Tags: python

Only just started learning Python a couple days ago.

When I type arguments, for example `print "Hello, World"`, is there a reason why I should (or shouldn't) put a space between `print` and the string? or if I want the variable `name = raw_input ("name?")`, should I have a spave between `name`, `=`, `raw_input` etc? It seems to work fine without, but I don't want to start getting bad habits that will bite me in the future.

Comment: Put the space.  Your fellow programmer who has to read your code will thank you.

Comment: Clarity? You want people to be able to read the code, yourself included...

Comment: Why do some of these answers not appear under "Answers"? I'm looking at you, Robert Harvey and Ben...

Comment: They're not answers @Demonic, they're comments... I didn't want to post a full answer so I commented instead. You can comment on your own posts but not on other people's until you reach 50 reputation. They're normally used for requesting clarification but in some cases are used for simple answers that others can then expand into full answers. See the [faq].

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks! Now I have to try to learn 'python' AND 'stack overflow' at the same time! Woop!

Comment: @Demonic, Stack Overflow is easy; you just have to remember a few things. If you're interested there is one blog post I would suggest you read: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ and have a look through [ask]. They give you guidance on how to ask good questions, which may help you in the future.

Comment: @Demonic, another good Stack Overflow habit to get into is to accept an answer to most questions you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
print"What's ur name?"
name=raw_input("Name: ")
print"Ok your name is %s."%name
```

The code above will work fine. Without errors.
But read the code. It doesn't look nice and the level of readability is less. And if you write huge amounts of code like that, it'd make your head spin the next time you read it.

And this same code written as:

```
print "What's ur name?"
name = raw_input("Name: ")
print "Ok your name is %s" % name
```

This makes the code more readable and looks better.
So the answer to your question is that its to make your code organized and readable to you and others.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. I knew it made it clearer (more clear?), I just didn't know if it did anything else. 

I will try to get into the habit! :)

Comment: @ Demonic : You are welcome ^_^. And good luck to you on your Python leaning journey.

Answer (score 5):

Python does have its own style guide (PEP 8), and it's definitely worth your time to read it. As far as what you're saying:

```
    More than one space around an assignment (or other) operator to align it with another.

    x = 1
    y = 2
    long_variable = 3
```

More here: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe how quickly my question was answered! I shall use my spaces properly, and read the style guide!

Answer (score 1):

There's a style guide for python code - PEP 8. Whitespace is used to enhance readability. You should specifically take a look at [Whitespace in Expressions and Statements](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements), which basically says "Yes, add one space, but only one."

Comment: If I had enough of this "reputation" stuff, I would vote this up. Thanks!